# Why repository sends to constructor of ViewModel?

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel

I'm studying Google Architecture Components with `MVVM` and noticed that repository sends to constructor of `ViewModel`. The question is why repository can't exist as a property, field in `ViewModel`? Some developers create `Factories` where repository is stored and initialize ViewModel with it. What is the reason to do so? `MVVM` tells that `View` does not have to know about `Model` at all. So, why repository does not just stay at `ViewModel` as a field?

Comment: The view should still not need to know about repository....it's typically passed in to `ViewModel` by `ViewModelFactory` which in turn is injected in to View (using something like `Dagger`).  If you use Koin instead this interaction is somewhat simplified.

Comment: The question is why `ViewModel` needs repository specifically in constructor? What stops repository to exist in ViewModel as a property?

Comment: It effectively is a property.  Is your question more about how/where it's instantiated?  If so, you ideally don't want to instantiate it in your ViewModel.  Having it externally injected means for example that you can plug in mock implementaiton of your repository during testing

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to know best practice about how to keep repository in ViewModel. What kind of difficulties can occur if repository is instantiated internally in ViewModel?

Comment: The main issue is that you wouldn't be able to easily configure a different instance of repository to be used in ViewModel....for example in the case of unit testing the ViewModel as mentioned you'd typically want to inject a mock implementation of repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically the repository doesn't change over the lifetime of the ViewModel. Supplying it as a parameter of the contrustor instead of a property ensures that it can't be changed, and code in the ViewModel can rely on it.

If it was a property, it could be changed during the lifetime of the ViewModel. Your code could load an object from one database and find the repository pointing to a different database when it needed to save.

Answer (score 1):

It is overall bad practice. Better is injecting in ViewModel for better testing.

Comment: Injection via constructor or are you assuming the project must use some sort of dependency injection?